# Update same datas im mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have updating the mysql datas from php

```
$sql_user = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user SET firstname = '".$fname."', lastname = '".$lname."', mobilenumber = '".$mobilenumber."'");
$rows_count = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
```

Here, After updating, It returns rows count.

When updating same datas to the table, It returns 0.

My question is,

If updating is successful, It may be same data or different data, I want to get success info.

Here i am using `mysqli_affected_rows($con)`. For that i have finding success or failure. But it is not applicable for same data updating.

How to get success or failure after updating datas(same Data or different Data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) returns count only if rows are updated.

If you update with the same data existing it the table.

E.g. `UPDATE users SET name='Dan'` where `name` is already `Dan`, then it will return `0` rows.

To overcome this, we need to have a out of box solution.

Add an `updated_date` field in DB table. Which should be `DATETIME`.

Whenever you fire an UPDATE query, change this field to `now()`.

Thus, row will updated and you will get count.

And eventually, your `mysql_num_rows()` will return something greater than `0`.

Comment: I don't see any need to update the `updated_date` if there was no data change in table. MySQL default behavior is good which returns zero rows affected if there is no change made

Comment: @Saqueib, The question states that it should return affected rows. Its not that it should update or not.

Comment: so if i say what was updated (affected) in table at time of `updated_date` the answer is `updated_date` (timestamp) only

Answer (score -1):

You cant check for affected rows since there is no change made in rows because of same data

`mysqli_affected_rows($con)` will return 0, one thing you can do to see query was success is check like this

```
$sql_user = mysqli_query($con,
                  "UPDATE user SET 
                       firstname = '".$fname."', 
                       lastname = '".$lname."', 
                       mobilenumber = '".$mobilenumber."'"
            );

// check here if its true your query was success
if($sql_user && mysqli_affected_rows($con) <= 0) 
{

}
```

then you can get success or failure after updating datas(same Data or different Data).

Answer (score -1):

You are missing  condition like " **where id=2** " in your query..

```
$sql_user = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user SET firstname = '".$fname."', lastname = '".$lname."', mobilenumber = '".$mobilenumber."' where id=2");
$rows_count = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
```